# Different results with and without a dummy WITH clause

Tags: database, select, mdx, olap

I'm trying to diagnose a bug in a calculated measure in a SSAS cube, and while debugging I get this weird behaviour ...

```
select
    [Measures].[Net Lost Commitments] on columns 
  , {[Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year].[2009\10],[Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year].[2010\11]} on rows
from Compass3
```

...returns the following:

```
       Net Lost Commitments
2009\10  (null)
2010\11  9,937
```

I'm trying to figure out why the value for 2009\10 is null and so I've been adding various other calculations via a WITH clause to help track back the problem. But any WITH clause I add changes the results, even if the calculation in the WITH clause is not used. For instance ...

```
with
    member [Measures].[test] as null
select
    [Measures].[Net Lost Commitments] on columns 
  , {[Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year].[2009\10],[Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year].[2010\11]} on rows
from Compass3
```

...returns the following:

```
       Net Lost Commitments
2009\10  8,783
2010\11  9,937
```

Have you ever seen that before? What could possibly be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the presence of the calculated member is affecting the solve order for the [Date Dimension] aggregation? Is [Net Lost Commitments] a calculated measure? And if so, can you change its solve order to later in the query processing?

Comment: I can see some sense to that and will experiment tomorrow.

Comment: My experiments seem to indicate that is not the problem. I tried two approaches to changing solver order: adding SOLVE_ORDER with various values to the WITH clause; and changing the order of the measure definitions in the cube's calculation script. Neither changed the effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-crafted the measure definitions into a simpler form and this problem seems to have gone away. I still have no idea how this seemingly random behaviour occurs but it is no longer an issue.

--Matt.